# How to Autofill and login into a website from external login page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, curl

Different customers use different websites to log-in to their account. i want to provide them a single form to put their credentials onto it, and select the domain/platform t they want themselves log in to and those credentials are passed to the desired website's login form log them into it. So, help me to send the credentials to the website. You can see the login form @ www.ubfmgps.com/login.html

Here is my html form to get the credentials

```
 <form  action="#" id="gaq-form" class="form-b" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <p>
                            <span>
                                <label for="fba">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName" autocomplete="on" required>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <label for="fbb">Password</label>
                                <input type="Password" id="txtUserPassword" name="txtUserPassword" required>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <solid>Choose Platform</solid>
                            <select name="platform" id="platform" width=100px>
                            <p> <option value="Jimishare" id="Jimishare">Jimishare</option>
                                <option value="Tracksolid" id="Tracksolid">Tracksolid</option>
                                <option value="Gpsyeah" id="Gpsyeah">Gpsyeah</option>
                            </select>
                            </p>
                        </p>
                        <p><button type="submit" onclick="login();">Log Me In</button></p>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                         function login()
                        {

                            if(document.getElementById("platform").value=='Jimishare')
                            {
                                var txtUserName = document.getElementById("username").value;
                                var txtUserPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
                                $.ajax({ 
                                    url : "http://www.jimishare.com",
                                    type : 'post', 
                                    data : 'txtUserName=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + 'txtUserPassword=' + encodeURIComponent(password), 
                                    dataType : 'json', 
                                    error : function(data) { console.log("error"); console.error(data); }, 
                                    success : function(data) { console.log("success"); console.info(data); } 
                                });
                            }
                            else if (document.getElementById("platform").value=='Tracksolid') {
                                document.write("Tracksolid");
                                var account = document.getElementById("username").value;
                                var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
                                $.ajax({ 
                                    url : "http://www.tracksolid.com/mainFrame",
                                    type : 'post', 
                                    data : 'account=' + encodeURIComponent(account) + 'password=' + encodeURIComponent(password), 
                                    dataType : 'json', 
                                    error : function(data) { console.log("error"); console.error(data); }, 
                                    success : function(data) { console.log("success"); console.info(data); } 
                                });

                            }
                            else {
                                document.write("Gpsyeah");
                            }
                        }
                        </script>
```

Comment: This would require either a browser extension or control of the target form. Are either of these things options for you? If so you would pull the information from the post/get data. The location of the centralized form should be white listed by the target login screens and use SSL. Also why are you not entertaining a Single Sign On system?

Comment: Like @ktamlyn mentioned, you're likely looking for a Single Sign On (SSO) system. Proxying authentication sessions yourself would be quite tricky with pitfalls for vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said, you are looking for a SSO system. Anyway, if you want to make a quick login system, you have to add some javascript to perform this operation.

You need to define a mapping which describe the username and password fields name for each sites. Assuming you have jQuery, you can try like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    form = $("#gaq-form");
    websitePickerField = $("select[name='platform']");
    usernameField = $("#username");
    passwordfield = $("#password");
    submitBtn = $('#submit');    

    form.submit(function() {
      updateFormAttrs($(this).val());
    });
});

function updateFormAttrs(currentWebsite) {
    var options = mapping[currentWebsite];
  form.attr('action', options.url);
  usernameField.attr('name', options.usernameName);
  passwordfield.attr('name', options.passwordName);
  submitBtn.attr('name', options.submitName);
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79dayp98/1/)

Comment: Let me be clear, through an example : I have 100 customers out of which 25 -30 login to jimishare ( ids for username and password are txtUserName and txtUserPassword respectively, submit btn id is sbmlogin), next set of customers have their credentials for tracksolid ( ids for username and password are account and password respectively , submit button id is logins) and rest set of customer have their credentials for justtrack and the ids of that 3rd party website form is different. all those platforms are not mine, those are 3rd party but we pay few penny to use their platforms.

Comment: To make ease of accessing the website rather than giving different different website to log in we want to give them our single log in form where respective customer choose respective platform and then we want to map up the credentials based on their chosen platform and will land on to logged in website.

Comment: just updated my answer. Hope this will solve your problem ;-)